# Write the function startEndVowels(word) that returns True if the word starts and ends with vowels

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

For the below program am getting output as:

```
True
False
None
False
```

Expected should be :

```
True
False
True
False
```

What is wrong with the code?

```
def startEndVowels(word):
    vowels = "aeiou"
    x = word[0]
    y = word[-1]
    z = len(word)
    if z >1:
       if x in vowels:
          if y in vowels:
             return True
       else:
            return False
    elif z == 1:
         if word in vowels:
            return True
         elif x == " ":
              return False
print startEndVowels("apple")
print startEndVowels("goole")
print startEndVowels("A")
print startEndVowels(" ")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use the [`startswith`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) and [`endswith`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) method which accept a `tuple` of possible prefixes/suffixes:

```
def startEndVowels(word):
    vowels = tuple("aeiouAEIOU")  
    return word.startswith(vowels) and word.endswith(vowels)
```

The reason why your function didn't work was because you didn't check the capitalization. You either need to include the upper case vowels too:

```
vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"
```

or cast the word to lower-case:

```
word = word.lower()
```

Answer (score 1):

The case with `startEndVowels("A")` is failing because you did not identify upper case vowels as such. So do:

```
vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"
```

Note that your code still fails for an empty string, and in some conditions the function does not return a value (so it is `None`): you should make sure to always `return`.

When you have this pattern for a boolean condition:

```
if condition:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

... then just do:

```
return condition
```

Also use `and` to join conditions. So you can do it like this:

```
def startEndVowels(word):
    vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"
    return len(word) > 0 and word[0] in vowels and word[-1] in vowels
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = word[0].lower()
y = word[-1].lower()
```

Also if condition not required on length>=1 but for length=0.

Comment: Just a note: That approach would fail on an empty string with an `IndexError`

Comment: If condition should for length =0 not for >=1.

Answer (score -1):

```
def startEndVowels(word):
    vowels='aeiou'
    if len(word)>1:
        if word[0].lower()in vowels and word[len(word)-1].lower() in vowels:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    elif len(word)==1:
        if word[0].lower() in vowels:
            return True
    elif word =='' :
        return False
```

Comment: This returns `True`, `False`, `True`, `None` and is therefore not the output wanted.